# xcode: How to specify clang version using GCC_VERSION field?

Tags: xcode, gcc, llvm, clang

I'm running Xcode4.5. Our project started with older Xcode and specifies compiler version using a meta-file that says

```
GCC_VERSION = com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
```

As far as I know this points to older version of LLVM and I wonder where I can find the canonical version number that specifies the latest LLVM (4.1) with Xcode4.5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as I know this points to older version of LLVM and I wonder where I can find the canonical version number that specifies the latest LLVM (4.1) with Xcode4.5?

Actually, `GCC_VERSION = com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0` points to the clang toolset referred by Xcode's "Locations".

So just specify the toolset in "Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Locations (Tab) > Command Line Tools" and then use `GCC_VERSION = com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0` to specify clang as the compiler. The toolset you specify in Preferences then defines the version/build of clang you are using.

Comment: Also for you _terminal freaks_ out there..  `xcodebuild -sdk macosx10.X -arch x86_64 GCC_VERSION=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0`...